# Laravel not showing icons after git pull

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am relatively new in Laravel and I'm dealing a problem with icons. I have an icons folder into laravel's public directory. The problem is that after git pull, icons doesn't load and I have to rename the icon's folder again and again. Why `asset('images/icon.png')` not working and if I change the icons folder name and set the new file name in link, icons are shown properly? e.g `asset('renamed_image_folder/icon.png')`

Comment: Although I have never had nor heard of this issue I would suggest you attept some of the asset cache handling procedures prior to and possibly after a git pull. Try running php artisan clear-compiled then composer dump-autoload Hope this helps

Comment: It can also be a matter of permissions. Do you call git pull as the same user you perform renaming folder?

Comment: It was permission error you was right!Thank you so much!